# toggleClass not closing div once opened

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some really simple lines of jQuery that are meant to open and close a div when clicking a link. When I click, the div opens fine (and any other open div, will close, which is good). But, when I click the link again the div will not close! I cannot figure out why. Any help would be much appreciated!

HTML:

```
<a href="../partial-2" id="products">
     <div class="products">
       <p>products</p>
     </div>
 </a>
 <div class="row product-options products-house shadow">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        ....content here, removed for brevity....
     </div>
  </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#products").on("click", function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $(".active-product").removeClass("active-product");
     $(".products-house.shadow").toggleClass("active-product");
});
```

In my CSS, I just have a display:none for the products-option, and display: block for active-product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While removing the class exclude the `.products-house.shadow` element using **[`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** pseudo-class selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#products").on("click", function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $(".active-product:not(.products-house.shadow)").removeClass("active-product");
     //        --------^^^^----------------------^^^^------
     $(".products-house.shadow").toggleClass("active-product");
});
```

Comment: Ah, that worked! Thank you! I guess it was just re-adding the class each time?

Comment: @bjorkland : `toggleClass` always add the class  since `removeClass` already removed the class